# Quickly Select Random Rows With Where Condition

Tags: mysql, random, sql-order-by, where-clause

Is it possible to quickly select random rows from a table, while also using a where condition?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM geo WHERE placeRef = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This can take 10+ seconds.

I found this, which is sometimes quick, sometimes very slow:

```
(SELECT *
FROM geo
INNER JOIN ( SELECT RAND() * ( SELECT MAX( nameRef ) FROM geo ) AS ID ) AS t ON geo.nameRef >= t.ID
WHERE geo.placeRef = 1
ORDER BY geo.nameRef
LIMIT 1)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast) provides a quick result, only if there is no extra where condition.

This is the create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `geo` (
 `nameRef` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
 `placeRef` mediumint(7) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `category` enum('continent','country','region','subregion') COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `parentRef` mediumint(7) DEFAULT NULL,
 `incidence` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `percent` decimal(11,9) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `ratio` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `rank` mediumint(7) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 KEY `placeRef_rank` (`placeRef`,`rank`),
 KEY `nameRef_category` (`nameRef`,`category`),
 KEY `nameRef_parentRef` (`nameRef`,`parentRef`),
 KEY `nameRef_placeRef` (`nameRef`,`placeRef`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

N.B. this table has around 550 million rows.

Desired query: query the table where placeRef = x; and then quickly return one row.

Issue: a query like `SELECT * FROM geo WHERE placeRef = 1` can provide up to about 15 million results. So selecting a single random row is slow.

Answer (score 1):

That technique is variable because it depends on where the matching rows happen to lie in the table.

The quick fix may be to add this index, assuming that `nameRef` is the `PRIMARY KEY` for the table:

```
INDEX(placeRef, nameRef)
```

Let's discuss this further after

- You provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE geo`
- You read http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

There are (currently) 3 indexes that make this subquery very fast (because of the leading `nameRef`):

```
( SELECT MAX( nameRef ) FROM geo )
```

After that, my suggestion of `(placeRef, nameRef)` will kick in for these:

```
WHERE geo.placeRef = 1
geo.nameRef >= t.ID
```

I think the resulting query should be consistently fast.

Comment: Added above. The `nameRef` is not relevant. I am seeking to get a random nameRef. There is no primary key for the table, as there is no need to identify rows on their own. placeRef, nameRef is a unique index.

Comment: @KohjahBreese - Every table needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.  If the pair `(placeRef, nameRef)` is unique and not null, make it the PK.  That will possibly speed up your query.  Note that I deliberately put `placeRef` first.

Comment: @KohjahBreese - However, due to the likely uneven distribution of the nameRef values, your query will produce a not-so-random result.

Answer (score 0):

This is pulling a result in 1/100th of a second:

```
SELECT * FROM geo where placeRef = 1 AND nameRef >= CEIL( RAND() * ( SELECT MAX( nameRef ) FROM forenameGeo ) ) LIMIT 1
```

This works well if you have an index on both the columns you would like to query. However, you may need to make a new table that is randomly ordered. In my table the nameRefs tend to be grouped by country. This causes the random results to be selected from a handful of results as most of the resulted are grouped around the same Id. I needed to create a new table ordered randomly `ORDER BY RAND()` where each row had a unique Id. Now I search this much smaller summary table with:

```
SELECT * FROM geoSummary where placeRef = 1 AND nameRef >= CEIL( RAND() * ( SELECT MAX( id ) FROM geoSummary ) ) LIMIT 1
```

Though to cut that `SELECT MAX` query running all the time I have saved the maximum Id in the server-side code, generate the random number there and run:

```
SELECT * FROM geoSummary where placeRef = 1 AND nameRef >= :random_number LIMIT 1
```

This provides truly random results.